# translate dutch sql data to english

Tags: sql-server-2005, translate

i currently have a dutch sql 2005 database and would like to hopefully convert a good portion of it to english if possible.  I have scoured google for options however im at a loss.  Some sites are suggesting a wordlist database (from TT Solutions) however the most complete one that i could find is $2000.  Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fluent in any other language but from my experience of automated translation services they will never provide the quality of translation a human can give.

Not that automated translation is all bad, I think it's amazing they can do it, but if you are working on a commercial product you should invest the money in having it translated properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you really are prepared to accept the bizarre output of a word-for-word translation, you can go looking for a free dictionary. for example, there's [this one](http://www.planetfreebook.com/world_of_words/%5bunknown%5d!Dutch-english%20%28dictionnaire%29.pdf).

However, unless you really have a database of single words, the results of this process are likely to involve many "hovercraft filled with eels."

Answer (score 0):

maybe automate some calls to an online babelfish implementation.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: thank you. please refer to the other 'answers' here for context on the level of response this question is generating.